# When state gets modified in function, and then later in the same function I use the state, the state is not updated. It is still unmodified

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-props

Problem explaination:
I have a function, in this function I make a REST delete request.
After this REST delete I fetch the new Data.
When i then want to work with the new data in the same function, right after I fetched the new data, I still have the old Data, with the object I just deleted.

Parent pseudo code:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [listOfMessages, setListOfMessages] = useState();
   
   async function fetchMessages() {
    let response = await //Make rest call to get Messages
    setListOfMessages(response);
   }

   async function deleteMessage(messageId) {
    await //Make rest call to delete message with id
    fetchMessages(response);
   }

  return (
    <Child deleteMessage = {deleteMessage} fetchMessage = {fetMessage} listOfMessages ={listOfMessages}/>
  )


}
```

Child pseudo code:

```
const Parent = (props) => {

async function handleDeletetButtonClick() {

  //Delete newest message
  await props.deleteMessage(0)

  //Fetch Messages
  await props.fetchMessages()

  //Display all messages, here it does still contain message 0, which i just deleted
  console.log(props.listOfMessages)
}


  return (
        <Button onClick={handleDeletetButtonClick}/>
  )


}
```

I put everywhere the await keyword, everything gets executed in the right order, first it gets deleted, when that is finished the new messages get fetched and after that the messages get printed to the console. I verified this with consol.log at the end of every function. My current explaination is that the component needs to get rerendered, in order to get the new props, with the new data, how would i achieve this? If my assumption is correct.

I have a workaround, but maybe there is a better solution.

Workaround:
Delete the Message myself with setListOfMessages() in the function and then resume as normal.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `deleteMessage` function, are you using `useState()` to update the contents of `listOfMessages`? You need to use React methods such as `useState` in order for your child component to get the new props automatically and re-render.

You should give us more details about how exactly `deleteMessage` is implemented.

Comment: No, inside the deleteMessage i do not use useState to update the state, but later in the function fetchMessages gets called and there the state gets updated with setListOfMessages(). So it should be fine. And there isnt much more info to the delete function, i just did not write the delete request out. Otherwisw everything is there.

Comment: You ought to update the state properly in the `deleteMessage` function. Also, looks like you might have a typo here in your return statement in the parent component: `fetchMessage = {fetMessage}`